# Connectivity issues in replication process

Tags: replication, mongodb

I've been trying to add a new node to a replica set without success due to these errors:

> 2019-08-12T06:48:15.031+0200 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0]
>   Ending connection to host mongo03:27017 due to bad connection status;
>   1 connections to that host remain open 2019-08-12T06:48:15.031+0200 I
>   REPL     [replication-224] Restarting oplog query due to error:
>   NetworkInterfaceExceededTimeLimit: error in fetcher batch callback:
>   Operation timed out. Last fetched optime (with hash): { ts:
>   Timestamp(1565585283, 1317), t: 9 }[1741433982986566690]. Restarts
>   remaining: 10 2019-08-12T06:48:15.032+0200 I REPL
>   [replication-224] Scheduled new oplog query Fetcher source:
>   mongo03:27017 database: local query: { find: "oplog.rs", filter: { ts:
>   { $gte: Timestamp(1565585283, 1317) } }, tailable: true, oplogReplay:
>   true, awaitData: true, maxTimeMS: 2000, batchSize: 13981010, term: 9,
>   readConcern: { afterOpTime: { ts: Timestamp(1565585283, 1317), t: 9 }
>   } } query metadata: { $replData: 1, $oplogQueryData: 1,
>   $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" } } active: 1
>   findNetworkTimeout: 7000ms getMoreNetworkTimeout: 10000ms shutting
>   down?: 0 first: 1 firstCommandScheduler: RemoteCommandRetryScheduler
>   request: RemoteCommand 2262327 -- target:mongo03:27017 db:local cmd:{
>   find: "oplog.rs", filter: { ts: { $gte: Timestamp(1565585283, 1317) }
>   }, tailable: true, oplogReplay: true, awaitData: true, maxTimeMS:
>   2000, batchSize: 13981010, term: 9, readConcern: { afterOpTime: { ts:
>   Timestamp(1565585283, 1317), t: 9 } } } active: 1
>   callbackHandle.valid: 1 callbackHandle.cancelled: 0 attempt: 1
>   retryPolicy: RetryPolicyImpl maxAttempts: 1 maxTimeMillis: -1ms
>   2019-08-12T06:48:17.637+0200 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0]
>   Connecting to mongo03:27017 2019-08-12T06:48:17.645+0200 I ASIO
>   [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo03:27017,
>   took 8ms (2 connections now open to mongo03:27017)
>   2019-08-12T06:49:36.961+0200 I -        [repl writer worker 13]
>   DB.CollectionName collection clone progress: 221390504/643329790
>   34% (documents copied) 2019-08-12T06:51:52.859+0200 I ASIO
>   [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Ending connection to host mongo03:27017
>   due to bad connection status; 1 connections to that host remain open
>   2019-08-12T06:51:52.859+0200 I REPL     [replication-229] Restarting
>   oplog query due to error: NetworkInterfaceExceededTimeLimit: error in
>   fetcher batch callback: Operation timed out. Last fetched optime (with
>   hash): { ts: Timestamp(1565585502, 204), t: 9 }[3285716995067894969].
>   Restarts remaining: 10 2019-08-12T06:51:52.859+0200 I ASIO
>   [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo03:27017
>   2019-08-12T06:51:52.859+0200 I REPL     [replication-229] Scheduled
>   new oplog query Fetcher source: mongo03:27017 database: local query: {
>   find: "oplog.rs", filter: { ts: { $gte: Timestamp(1565585502, 204) }
>   }, tailable: true, oplogReplay: true, awaitData: true, maxTimeMS:
>   2000, batchSize: 13981010, term: 9, readConcern: { afterOpTime: { ts:
>   Timestamp(1565585502, 204), t: 9 } } } query metadata: { $replData: 1,
>   $oplogQueryData: 1, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" } }
>   active: 1 findNetworkTimeout: 7000ms getMoreNetworkTimeout: 10000ms
>   shutting down?: 0 first: 1 firstCommandScheduler:
>   RemoteCommandRetryScheduler request: RemoteCommand 2272962 --
>   target:mongo03:27017 db:local cmd:{ find: "oplog.rs", filter: { ts: {
>   $gte: Timestamp(1565585502, 204) } }, tailable: true, oplogReplay:
>   true, awaitData: true, maxTimeMS: 2000, batchSize: 13981010, term: 9,
>   readConcern: { afterOpTime: { ts: Timestamp(1565585502, 204), t: 9 } }
>   } active: 1 callbackHandle.valid: 1 callbackHandle.cancelled: 0
>   attempt: 1 retryPolicy: RetryPolicyImpl maxAttempts: 1 maxTimeMillis:
>   -1ms

I'm a little bit lost regarding how to debug it. 
It's a 250GB database, the synchronization is being done through a private network 100Mb. There is an iptables in all servers but the traffic from the private network is allowed:

```
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 27017 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

At some point the replication process fails:

> 2019-08-12T02:22:37.582+0200 I REPL     [replication-143] Restarting
>   oplog query due to error: ExceededTimeLimit: error in fetcher batch
>   callback: Executor error during find command :: caused by :: errmsg:
>   "oper ation exceeded time limit". Last fetched optime (with hash): {
>   ts: Timestamp(1565569328, 710), t: 9 }[7908135344534364729]. Restarts
>   remaining: 1 2019-08-12T02:22:37.582+0200 I REPL     [replication-143]
>   Scheduled new oplog query Fetcher source: mongo03:27017 database:
>   local query: { find: "oplog.rs", filter: { ts: { $gte:
>   Timestamp(1565569328, 710) } },  tailable: true, oplogReplay: true,
>   awaitData: true, maxTimeMS: 2000, batchSize: 13981010, term: 9,
>   readConcern: { afterOpTime: { ts: Timestamp(1565569328, 710), t: 9 } }
>   } query metadata: { $replData: 1, $oplogQ ueryData: 1,
>   $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" } } active: 1
>   findNetworkTimeout: 7000ms getMoreNetworkTimeout: 10000ms shutting
>   down?: 0 first: 1 firstCommandScheduler: RemoteCommandRetryScheduler
>   re quest: RemoteCommand 1381614 -- target:mongo03:27017 db:local cmd:{
>   find: "oplog.rs", filter: { ts: { $gte: Timestamp(1565569328, 710) }
>   }, tailable: true, oplogReplay: true, awaitData: true, maxTimeMS:
>   2000, ba tchSize: 13981010, term: 9, readConcern: { afterOpTime: { ts:
>   Timestamp(1565569328, 710), t: 9 } } } active: 1 callbackHandle.valid:
>   1 callbackHandle.cancelled: 0 attempt: 1 retryPolicy: RetryPolicyImpl
>   maxAttem pts: 1 maxTimeMillis: -1ms 2019-08-12T02:22:39.612+0200 I
>   REPL     [replication-142] Error returned from oplog query (no more
>   query restarts left): ExceededTimeLimit: error in fetcher batch
>   callback: Executor error during find command ::  caused by :: errmsg:
>   "operation exceeded time limit" 2019-08-12T02:22:39.615+0200 I REPL
>   [replication-142] Finished fetching oplog during initial sync:
>   ExceededTimeLimit: error in fetcher batch callback: Executor error
>   during find command :: caused by :: errms g: "operation exceeded time
>   limit". Last fetched optime and hash: { ts: Timestamp(1565569328,
>   710), t: 9 }[7908135344534364729] 2019-08-12T02:22:43.034+0200 I REPL 
>   [replication-142] CollectionCloner ns:DB.CollectionName finished
>   cloning with status: IllegalOperation: AsyncResultsMerger killed
>   2019-08-12T02:22:44.551+0200 W REPL     [replication-142] collection
>   clone for 'DB.CollectionName' failed due to IllegalOperation: While
>   cloning collection 'DB.CollectionName' there was an error
>   'AsyncResultsMerger killed' 2019-08-12T02:22:44.551+0200 I REPL
>   [replication-142] CollectionCloner::start called, on ns:DB.CollectionName2
>   2019-08-12T02:22:44.551+0200 W REPL     [replication-142] database
>   'dbName' (9 of 9) clone failed due to ShutdownInProgress: collection
>   cloner completed 2019-08-12T02:22:44.551+0200 I REPL
>   [replication-142] Finished cloning data: ShutdownInProgress:
>   collection cloner completed. Beginning oplog replay.
>   2019-08-12T02:22:44.551+0200 I REPL     [replication-142] Initial sync
>   attempt finishing up.

And it has to start over again.

Don't know if I could configure a bigger time out to avoid this disconnections.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What specific versions of MongoDB server (x.y.z) are you running on your existing and new replica set members?

Comment: @Stenniedb version v3.6.13 in all the replica set nodes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check your connection time out settings on your mongo servers
2. Please try increasing the ulimit settings on your servers
3. Please implement retry logic in your driver level so the driver can handle this

Thank you!

-Anban